# HashMap and ArrayList confusion in retrieval

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have  a problem on arraylist and hashmap

As according to my requirement, I am storing the data into HashMap and after that I have created a List as List>.

```
        HashMap<String,String> hashmap;
        static List<HashMap<String,String>> hashmap_string;
```

And while retrieving the value from database and putting it on HashMap and ArrayList like:

```
                    contract_number=c.getString(c1);
                    Log.i("c1.getString,contract_number", contract_number);
                    String service_level=c.getString(c2);
                    hashmap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashmap.put(contract_number, service_level);
                    hashmap_string.add(hashmap);
```

And now I want to retrieve the value as String,String

And when I am applying the code as:

```
                for(int i=0;i<hashmap_string.size();i++)
                {
                    Log.i("arraylist", ""+hashmap_string.get(i));
                }
```

I am getting a single string value in the formet as

```
               {Contract,ServiveValue}
```

but I want to split this into 2 string values...Also these values are redundant and if am using hashMap then it will not showing me the redundant value.

Please help me on this..

Comment: Why you are not using only HashMap instead. If you need to get `Contract` and `ServiveValue` as single values I think it is better option to do.

Comment: It seems you are moving to design your data very badly. what you are trying to solve this way?

Comment: Beacause HashMap does not retrieve duplicate values and my contract and service level value has duplicate values

Comment: I just want to show this key and value in a listview .. And this key and value is having duplicate data..please suggest ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap (and Maps in general) are used for multiple one-to-one mappings of keys and values. Are you sure you need that? Looking at your code it appears you're using the map as a "Pair" class. I would skip the list, and put everything in the same map, and then iterate over the pairs in the map:

```
// using tree map to have entries sorted on the key, 
// rather than the key's hash value.
Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
data.put("c1", "s1");
data.put("c2", "s2");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    String contract = entry.getKey();
    String level = entry.getValue();
    Log.i("data", contract + " : " + level");
}
```

would output (assuming TreeSet):

```
c1 : s1
c2 : s2
```

Alternatively, create e.g. a ContractServiceLevel class that holds two strings (the contract number and the service level), and put instances of that class in your list.

EDIT:

```
public final class ContractServiceLevel {
    public final String number;
    public final String serviceLevel;

    public ContractServiceLevel(String c, String s) {
        number = c;
        serviceLevel = s;
    }
}

List<ContractServiceLevel> contracts = new ArrayList<ContractServiceLevel>();
contracts.add(new ContractServiceLevel("c1", "s1.1"));
contracts.add(new ContractServiceLevel("c1", "s1.2"));
contracts.add(new ContractServiceLevel("c2", "s2.1"));

for (ContractServiceLevel contract : contracts) {
    Log.i("data", contract.number + ":" + contract.servicveLevel);
}
```

would output:

```
c1 : s1.1
c1 : s1.2
c2 : s2.1
```

Comment: data.put("c1","s1"); and again data.put("c1",s1");    Now it will only return 1 pair as "c1","s1"...and my key and value both contain duplicate values..So how can I solve this

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing something. When you execute `hashmap_string.get(i)`, you will get the `<HashMap<String,String>`. So, This is the right value from code.

What you can do is :

```
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap2 = hashmap_string.get(i);
        String value = hashMap2.get("your_key");
```

Other way, you already have two splited string values. you can get that by using `keySet()` and `values()` methods over `hashMap2` Object.

Comment: Still it does not retrieve duplicate data

Answer (score -2):

String value = hashmap.get("contract");
u will be getting the value as ServiveValue